# Getting Frames from an Application

Tags: c#, screen-capture

I've been working on reliably getting each frame from a running Windows application in C#.

**My goal is to call a method each time an application's user interface updates, providing an image of the updated display as an argument**.

Here's the current code I've been experimenting with:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ApplicationFrameCapture
{
    class Program
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rect rectangle);

        public struct Rect
        {
            public int Left { get; set; }
            public int Top { get; set; }
            public int Right { get; set; }
            public int Bottom { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach(Process p in processes)
            {
                if (p.ProcessName.Equals("notepad"))
                {
                    Rect WindowRect = new Rect();
                    GetWindowRect(p.MainWindowHandle, ref WindowRect);

                    int width = WindowRect.Right - WindowRect.Left;
                    int height = WindowRect.Bottom - WindowRect.Top;
                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                    graphics.CopyFromScreen(WindowRect.Left, WindowRect.Top, 0, 0, new Size(width, height), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                    bmp.Save("c:/tmp/capture.png", ImageFormat.Png);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But there are some issues with this solution. The biggest issue, though, is that it leaves a border of about 7 pixels around the captured image for some reason.

[image]

I thought it could have had something to do with the shadow effect Windows puts on the application, but disabling the shadow effect ***didn't*** eliminate the border.

On top of that, though, my solution is on a request basis, so there's no way for me to capture the frame of an application as soon as the interface updates.

Thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: Can you expand your code sample to include everything required to run it?

Comment: This is specific to Win10, windows no longer have the fat border they used to have on previous Windows versions.  Borders are now transparent with a gradient (the "shadow" effect) easy to see if you move the mouse along the border.  Note how it still displays the sizing cursor, even though you hover the shadow.  GetWindowRect includes that border, like it always did before.  Cropping the image to trim off the gradient would be necessary to make it look better.  Not simple to do correctly since Win10 lies about its version number, consider GetClientRect().

Comment: I've made no progress on solving this question, but I do wonder if switching to a different language would make this easier. I'm open to suggestions.